# Does append() function add both index and value to another list?

Tags: python

Heres the code I'm trying to understand:

The code is the implementation of Sieve of Erastothenes. If I understand it correctly, then up to line 8, the code creates a list of prime numbers up to N and the list is  a boolean list where True - prime; False - non-prime; and the index number matches with the number we output.

My question is:
For lines 9-13 does the script "rewrite" the primes (which are just True values) with both the index and the boolean value in a new list in order for us to print them at the end?
Also, if primes is a boolean list, why python prints the index values at the end instead of just a bunch of True arguments?

Update: I got it, thanks guys! range is a set of integers from 2 - n+1, hence i is integer as well, thats why I get integers in the primes string. For some reason I was thinking of range as list1 initialy

```py
def sita(N):
    list1 = [True for _ in range(N + 1)]
    list1[0:1] = [False, False]
    for start in range(2, N + 1):
        if list1[start]:
            for i in range(2 * start, N + 1, start):
                list1[i] = False
    primes = []  #create empty list
    for i in range(2, N + 1):
        if list1[i]:
            primes.append(i)
    return primes
print(sita(int(input("Dati un numar N: "))))
```

Comment: primes is not a list of booleans. That's the entire point of the second loop. Can you clarify what you mean by "rewrite with both the index and boolean value"?

Comment: I mean, it takes the values which are True and rewrites them in a new list with the same old index and value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop, `for i in range(2, N + 1):` is looping over the actual indices. It *tests* the boolean value in `list1[i]`, but only stores the index. The boolean value (`list1[i]`) need not be written; the mere fact that you `append`ed `i` indicates that the test passed, and `i` is known to correspond to a prime number. Since `primes` is built from scratch, it contains no booleans at all, just the various `i` values (tested and found prime) `append`ed to it in the final loop.

Answer (score 0):

`primes.append(i)` only appends its argument, `i`.  There is no magic that would additionally append anything else to the list.

In your code, there are two separate, independent lists: `list1` and `primes`:

- The first contains a boolean for each non-negative integer.
- The second contains those integers for which `list1` contained `True` at the end of the first loop (this is what the `if list1[i]` check does).